# How do I make an EventHandler non-responsive to MouseMoved after a mouse click?

Tags: dynamic

Consider the following code. After evaluating it, when I move the mouse over the output `text`, it prints 1, and when I click the mouse on `text`, it prints 2.

```
EventHandler["text", {"MouseMoved" :> (Print[1]), "MouseDown" :> (Print[2])}]
```

I want to modify this so when I move the mouse over the output `text`, it prints 1, and when I click on `text`, it prints 2 and stops printing 1. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is by simply using a variable to flip `MouseMoved`'s action to none when `MouseDown` is triggered:

```
DynamicModule[{flag = True},
    EventHandler["text", 
        {"MouseMoved" :> If[flag, Print[1], ## &[]], 
         "MouseDown" :> (flag = False; Print[2])
    }]
]
```

Comment: I thought it was Rojo that uses `guard` and not you? Or were you referring to him?

Comment: Rojo, certainly.  I think his `guard` use is a great trick.

Comment: I get `Function::slotn: Slot number 1 in Hold[#1]& cannot be filled from (Hold[#1]&)[]. >>` errors from this when clicking the text.  Do you do too or is this a v7 issue?

Comment: Works fine in v8.0.4